# How can I create an always-expanded treeview?

Tags: wpf, treeview, expansion

Well, I thought I had this one solved.  I simply changed the TreeViewItem's template to ignore whether a particular node was expanded or not.  Looks great!  But that's just it... it *looks* great!  Keyboard navigation still responds as if the node was expanded or collapsed.

For instance, if I'm on the root node and hit the right arrow (nothing moves, nor should it) then hit down, I go to the first child of the root.  However, if I'm on the root node and hit left (again, nothing moves) then hit down, I jump to the second root node, jumping over all the first node's children!

Needless to say that's not the behavior we want.  We could simply swallow the left and right arrow keys, or simply abandon the treeview entirely and move to nested items presenters (which is sort of what a TreeView does anyway) but I'm hoping I don't have to re-create an entire control just for this functionality.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In your TreeViewItem template, you can set IsExpanded to true, and all of your items should then be expanded if they have child elements.

Unfortunately you may have to swallow those keystrokes to get the keyboard navigation you want, as the navigation you are seeing is by design.

You may be able to create a custom treeview inherited from TreeView and put those button events in there so that you can re-use it.

Comment: KeyDown specifically and any other key events that might occur when a user presses a key.  After a little thought, it sounds like you might be better served with a ListBox with items with itemtemplates to differentiate them.  You are looking for navigation that ListBox supports, you are not looking for collapsing groups, etc.  Child objects can have a margin or something to replicate the horizontal offset you see in a normal treeview.

Comment: The problem with nesting listboxes is the keyboard navigation there is even worse since every control is its own focus scope and tab navigation and such goes between the listboxes rather than treating them all as one.  Granted, I could template the crap out of that, but I'm just guessing a better thing to do would be to subscribe to the IsExpanded changed notification property of each TreeViewItem and simply ensure it stays true.)

Comment: It looks like ListBox can provide for grouping when populated with a CollectionViewSource where the View has had some grouping done on it.  Your items could be grouped by parent item, and should retain the listbox navigation.

Comment: No, the grouping in a listbox is for a fixed-depth of grouping, not arbitrary as a TreeView provides.  Plus, you can't select group 'nodes' in a grouping listbox.